# Intent extra key - getting a null value on consent intent extra key

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, google-api

I've been trying to implement Google API(https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request) and I am getting a null value from     **public static final String EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT = "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT";**

Here's my **consentIntent** variable

```
val consentIntent : Intent? = extras.getParcelable(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT)
```

I can't have **consentIntent** as null as it is needed to launch User Consent dialog box from client app.

Please help me in resolving this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could it be a problem of  deprecated key value?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: No, still no luck